# Using rails inside gem as a dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin, gemfile

While browsing through the [active-admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) code, I found that [Gemfile](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/Gemfile) contains the **rails** entry.

```
rails_version = detect_rails_version
gem 'rails', rails_version
```

Does that mean **active-admin** internally creates a rails server which is not the main rails app?

If **Yes**, will that lead to performance issues and using it with complex rails applications is a bad practice?

if **No**, what is the use of it in active-admin Gemfile?

Googled a lot with different keywords which only leads to gem install and related results.

I would be glad if somebody put some insights.
Thanks :)

**update1:**
After Gaurish answer and [googling](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/), it seems that Gemfile inside gem is used to list dependencies needed for gem internally. 
But it create another question, what happens when application gems and gems' gem conflits?

**update2:**
Can we use active-admin standalone, since it has rails as a dependency? (Just installing active-admin by `gem install active-admin` instead of keeping it in some other rails application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This seems a bundler issue. [this code](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/Gemfile#L9-L22) just declares a dependency on rails. sound's strange? Here is what I think is happening.

the usual way is to declare your dependencies in `.gemspec` file by using following line:

```
s.add_dependency("rails", ">= 3.0.0")
```

the above lines add a dependancy on rails `v3.0` & above(`v3.1`,`v3.2`). now this works fine for other gems & bundler will auto resolve dependencies. But when you try to support multiple versions of rails, bundler might get confused.

Ideally, bundler should be able to automatically bundle(install) all the dependencies of our gem. And also dependencies of gem dependencies. example, bundle should be smart enough to figure out if rails `v3.1` or `v3.2` is required, it also needs to include `sass-rails` & 'uglifier' as they required by rails 3.1 & 3.2. But if rails `v3.0` is required, nothing extra need to be done.

But we live in not so perfect world, so bundler is not smart enough. Hence, I think this is the reason `active-admin` has to resort to the following hack around bundler's shortcomings.

```
unless defined?(RAILS_VERSION_FILE)
  RAILS_VERSION_FILE = File.expand_path("../../../.rails-version", __FILE__)
end

unless defined?(DEFAULT_RAILS_VERSION)
  DEFAULT_RAILS_VERSION = "3.1.0"
end

def detect_rails_version
  return DEFAULT_RAILS_VERSION unless File.exists?(RAILS_VERSION_FILE)
  File.read(RAILS_VERSION_FILE).chomp
end

def write_rails_version(version)
  File.open(RAILS_VERSION_FILE, "w+"){|f| f << version }
end


rails_version = detect_rails_version
gem 'rails', rails_version

case rails_version
when /^3\.0/
  # Do nothing, bundler should figure it out
when /^3\.(1|2)/
  # These are the gems you have to have for Rails 3.1 to be happy
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
else
  raise "Rails #{rails_version} is not supported yet"
end
```

if you notice the above code, it checks if current version of rails is v3.1 or v3.2. if yes, then add new two as dependencies. That's all this code does.

---

[Update]

Questions
1. **what happens when application gems and gems' gem conflicts?** 
If they conflict in such a way that bundler can't find a compatible version that satisfies dependencies of your app and gems.   bundler will fail with an error something similar to this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In Gemfile:
    chef (~> 10.26) ruby depends on
      json (<= 1.7.7, >= 1.4.4) ruby

    berkshelf (~> 2.0) ruby depends on
      json (1.8.0)
```

Question 2. **Can we use active-admin standalone** 
without rails? No. when you do `gem install active-admin`, rubygems will auto install rails as its listed as a dependency of this gem in `gemspec` file.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but what you think, why would a [Gemfile](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/Gemfile) contain a reference to other gems(like bourbon), which is not really needed in normal rails app?

Comment: In general, a gem’s Gemfile should contain the Rubygems source and a single gemspec line but developers sometimes don't follow this advice. And that's what we are seeing here. see http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But in gem development Gemfile is used to write gems dependencies which are used inside the gem. By yahuda under **Ruby Libraries** last point.

Comment: Correct. so what your question?

Comment: Updated question to merge your answer.

Comment: Added answers to both of your questions